# How can I moq this query against ravendb

Tags: nunit, moq, ravendb

I have this code in my project, how can I use Moq to moq the documentsession and setup the return value?

```
_session.Query<IPageModel, PageByUrl>()
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Metadata.Url == virtualUrl);
```

This is what I have tried before I asked

```
var session = new Mock<IDocumentSession>();
var pageModel = new DummyModel();
session.Setup(x => x.Query<IPageModel, PageByUrl>()
.Customize(y => y.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite())
.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Metadata.Url == path)).Returns(pageModel);
```

This throws an exception and I can't figure out how to change the moq

```
System.NotSupportedException : Expression references a method that does not belong to the mocked object: x => x.Query<IPageModel,PageByUrl>().Customize(y => y.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfLastWrite()).FirstOrDefault<IPageModel>(y => y.Metadata.Url == .path)
at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass1c`2.<Setup>b__1b()
at Moq.Mock.Setup(Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Func`1 condition)
at Moq.Mock`1.Setup(Expression`1 expression)
at BrickPile.Tests.Web.Routing.PathResolverTests.Home_Page_With_Default_Action(String path) in PathResolverTests.cs: line 26
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of mocking the document session, have you thought about using the embeddabledocumentstore? It could run completely in memory and you have the full database as backend for your tests.

See also this blog post which describes some of the backgrounds: http://novuscraft.com/blog/ravendb-and-the-repository-pattern

Comment: I used embeddabledocumentstore as you suggested, it works great but maybe my unit test tests a bit to much code now. Thanks!

Comment: @Marcus where is the point regarding more code that is tested when you are using Moq? With this definition Moq is also additional code which is tested

Answer (score 6):

This question inspired a [blog post](http://www.truewill.net/myblog/index.php/2012/02/17/how_can_i_mock_x).

The short answer: **Don't.** You're coupling your application to RavenDB and violating the Interface Segregation Principle. Instead, write a custom interface that specifies precisely what services your class (the system under test) needs. Write a wrapper class that implements that and delegates to RavenDB. This might use the Repository Pattern, or it might be something simpler. Your interface should be simple to mock.

Comment: I have gone down that road earlier and in this case, with ravendb I didn't like it because creating an abstraction like a service hides the excellent client API that RavenDB has and will give me a lot of irrelevant code like this in my services http://cl.ly/EJsI , thanks though for your answer.

Comment: Good luck with the Ayende party line. Paraphrasing him: "YAGNI! Unnecessary abstraction! No need to unit test in isolation. Why would you ever replace RavenDB/NHibernate/etc.?" Maybe it works for him, but I don't see how it would work for the rest of us in all but the simplest of cases.

Comment: "maybe my unit test tests a bit to much code now." - Which is exactly my point.

Comment: The only drawback I can see for not abstracting away RavenDB is that it leads to somewhat slower unit tests. So it is still quicker to unit test something that is in isolation than to initialize the in-memory RavenDB and test that (it seems to lag the test for some seconds on my computer).

Comment: @Spoike - good to know. I think it's also better design, plus it gives you the option of quickly switching technologies if something better comes out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock whatever IDocumentSession.Query() returns as a separate mock so that you can then setup the customize call. I'm typing this on my phone so I can't easily give you an example.